# Initial sort of products pulled from MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have two very similar but different sites, each which display products on a listing page.  From there you can select an item and view details, just like a regular e-commerce site.  I want the default sort to be alphabetical.  I know my problem is that the erroneous site is not sorting products from db correctly, due to code issues on php product listing template page.  I'm just not 100% sure how to change the problematic site to sort/display products alphabetically by default.
Here is the code from template page that loads items from db - this is the one that functions correctly (alphabetical sort by default, when no other sorting specified

```
  // Load product from database
  $products = $db->rawQuery("SELECT {$productsCols},
                                {$productsImagesCols},
                                {$productsTypesCols}
                         FROM `products`
                         LEFT JOIN `products_images` ON     `products_images`.`id` = (SELECT `products_images`.`id`
                                                                              FROM `products_images`
                                                                              WHERE `products_images`.`pid` = `products`.`id`
                                                                            AND `products_images`.`featured` = ?
                                                                           LIMIT 1)
                         LEFT JOIN `types` ON `products`.`tid` = `types`.`id`
                         WHERE `products`.`status` LIKE ?
                         ORDER BY `products`.`name` ASC", array('true', 'enabled'));
```

Here is the code from the product listing template that does not sort alphabetically by default

```
// Load product from database
 $products = $db->rawQuery("SELECT {$productsCols},
                                {$productsImagesCols},
                                {$productsTypesCols}
                         FROM `products`
                         LEFT JOIN `products_images` ON    `products_images`.`id` = (SELECT `products_images`.`id`
                                                                              FROM `products_images`
                                                                           WHERE `products_images`.`pid` = `products`.`id`
                                                                              AND `products_images`.`featured` = ?
                                                                           LIMIT 1)
                         LEFT JOIN `types` ON `products`.`tid` = `types`.`id`
                         WHERE `products`.`status` LIKE ?
                         ORDER BY " . $sort_field . " ASC", array('true', 'enabled'));
  $products = (count($products) > 0) ? $products : false ;
```

I am almost certain my issue is due to this line:

```
ORDER BY " . $sort_field . " ASC", array('true', 'enabled'));
```

If anyone had any input as to how to change this problematic line or any other pieces of code, let me know!

FYI  this variable - $sort_field = '`products`.`sort_position`'; -- in the db sort_position is all the same (0) so this is not the issue as the first step I took was to change to zeros.

Thanks!

Comment: $sort_field should equal products.name

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So to clarify, $sort_field = 'products.sort_position'; should be $sort_field = 'products.name';

Comment: yessir, that should fix your issue